# Prove type questions

Tags: summation

Prove summation formula by counting a set in two ways

$$
(a)\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k-1}=2^{n}-1\,.
$$
$$
(b)\sum_{k=0}^n k{n \choose x} =n2^{n-1}
$$

Comment: The sums as you have written them diverge. Are you sure they are meant to go to infinity and not n? Also, what is x?

Comment: Sorry, that is my mistake. I fixed it already. @Mark

Comment: @Mark I fix it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a) let us look at the more general sum (the geometric sum):
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n r^{k-1}= 1+r+r^2+r^3+...+r^{k-1}$$
$$r*S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n r^{k}= r+r^2+r^3+...+r^{k}$$
$$S_n-r*S_n= (1+r+r^2+r^3+...+r^{n-1})-(r+r^2+r^3+...+r^{n})$$
$$S_n*(1-r)=1-r^n$$
$$S_n= \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$
The last result is the closed form of for the finite geometric series. In your problem r=2 so using this closed form:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k-1}=\frac{1-2^n}{1-2}=\frac{1-2^n}{-1}= 2^n-1.$$
Notice the sum converges to this value $\forall$ n, however, the sum does not converge $\forall$ r. It would only converge for r<1.

For part (b), what is x?

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem for me. There is no x for part b and the k should star from 0. @Mark

Comment: If you want to start from k=0 then you can make the substitution that k= k-1. Everything else works out the same way. For part b there is an x in the combinatorics, you have nCx.

Comment: I see I will try it, thank you for the help.